# How to center an inline <div>

Tags: html, css, layout, centering

I have a `<div>` with `display: inline;` property and I want to center it.

If I put margin: 0 auto works without display but I need the display not to take all the space like it's a block.

Html

```
<div id="login1">
<fieldset id="login2">
    <form method="post" action="register.php">
        <label>Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"><br>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="LogIn">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Css

```
#login1 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to center all the `<div>`

Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `text-align: center` on the container (the element that contains your div).

And your div shall be centered.

Comment: Where do I have to put the container?

Comment: By container, he means whatever is around the `#login1` element.

Comment: @Ninjacu The container is the element your div is in (not visible in the HTML you posted, so I cannot really show you). It is surely contained in some kind of element.

Comment: it's the containing element of `div#login1`, if there is one.  But most likely?  it's the div you're going to add that wraps `div#login1`

Comment: @Ninjacu No, you do not have to. You look at your HTML. Find your `#login1` div. And check the element that is around it. It can be `body`, or a different `div`, or anything else, I don't see it.

Comment: yes is the body, so I put text-align: center in the body?

Comment: yes it works! But the problem is that if in the future I want to put something in the body but not center I'll have a problem. Are there any solution like body div#login1 {text-align: center}?

Comment: @Ninjacu Then add appropriate containers (divs or anything else that fits there semantically) into your code. Oh, I also wanted to say, that the `fieldset` should be in the `form`, not vice versa.

Comment: Oh it works perfectly! I don't understand why it works but it works. If you want you can explain it to me. Thanks for all!